# Android Unit Test Cache

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm facing an issue whereby whenever I use adb command to run my android test case but it keeps a cache of the last test class. This is even though I have changed my code and rebuild.

I'm running below command

> `./adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.xxx.yyy.tests/SignInActivityTest com.xxx.yyy.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`

I add some test method, it is still caching and run the old test case.

Comment: can u be specific with your question..what u trying to do..what steps u are following??

Comment: hi nitesk, I m running below command
./adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.xxx.yyy.tests/SignInActivityTest com.xxx.yyy.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

I add some test method, it is still caching and run the old test case? nitesh please help

Comment: Have you tried running a build clean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using command line; Make sure to re-build the test application and not only the application under test and that both are deployed to the target before running tests again.